# Multiple Rails Apps same domain Passenger

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, passenger

I am trying to have two Rails applications run on the same Virtual Private Server.  I have only one domain name, so if the first app is example.com, the second app I am guessing would need to be example.com/second_app.  I tried following this article, since it appeared to be using the same tech as me (Passenger): https://beforeitwasround.com/2013/03/serving-multiple-rails-apps-under-one-virtual-host-with-phusion-passenger.html

Before taking the steps in that article, I deployed my second app to the server using the same instructions as the currently working first app (up to, but not including the part where you add a VirtualHost/config file for the app): https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/walkthroughs/deploy/ruby/digital_ocean/apache/oss/trusty/deploy_app.html

And I even restarted the primary app using the following command from the first app's directory:
passenger-config restart-app $(pwd)

The first app is still working, however, first_app.com/second_app does not appear to work as described in the first article. I am guessing there is a ton of knowledge assumed, however I am just starting with Rails, and am learning as I go. Do I need to create a VirtualHost/config file for the second app?

My specifics:
VPS: Digital Ocean
Ruby: 2.3.4
Rails: 4.2.5
Ubuntu: 16.04
Apache: 2.4.18
Passenger

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I figured out what I didn't know to do.  That is, I did not restart apache after editing the VirtualHost/config file:

```
sudo apache2ctl restart
```

Which then gave me the error:
"AH00526: Syntax error on line 19 of /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/test_app.conf:
Either all Options must start with + or -, or no Option may"

Upon googling the error, It appears that there was a syntax error in the code from the article I read. Which doesn't surprise me, as the article is 4-5 years old.  But i'm surprised that it was as easy as changing:

```
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
```

to

```
Options +Indexes +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
```

My second app now correctly shows when I go to the link now!  Very psyched.